# Garmin Heart Rate Monitor Not Reporting Accurate HR Anymore

Tags: accessories, bike-computer, heart-rate

With my first Garmin Edge 305, I got the cadence and heart rate accessories. Cadence is still humming along, but the heart rate monitor has been not accurately reporting heart rate over the past couple months.

Two battery changes and various attempts to wet the contacts and my skin beneath have not resurrected the reliability of the heart rate monitor strap.

Do you all have any further suggestions to try to get the Garmin Heart Rate Monitor working properly again, or is it time to just bite the bullet and buy a replacement heart rate monitor strap. If so, another Garmin-branded one or a different ANT+ heart rate monitor?

Comment: What does it do when its inaccurate?  Have you tried thoroughly washing the strap to remove (conductive) salt residue?

Comment: Given the battery changes, if you haven't washed the strap, try doing that, first with soap and water, then wipe with isopropyl alcohol. If you get no different response, replace the strap. BTW, I recently had to replace my Edge 305 because the PC drivers were blue screening my Win 7 PC. If you use the Garmin software at all, you might consider an overall upgrade. In addition, they've changed the design f the Garmin HR strap, so if you do decide to replace it, it will be with the newer soft strap, not the same as your original one.

Comment: What exactly does inaccurate mean? Too low a number? Too high? Sometimes works, and sometimes not?

Comment: @zenbike Inaccurate in the fact it's way too low, both the realtime reading, and the average as a product of that. I'll try cleaning it as you both have suggested.

Comment: Maybe you're dead?

Comment: @lawndartcatcher -- He's just hibernating.  It'll work fine come spring.

Comment: What can happen is that the unit begins picking up respiration or even RPMs rather than heartbeat.  This seems to be usually related to conductive salts making the pickup area too large.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a nice wash, though would I visibly see the salt's buildup. It's pretty clean.
Also thought it might be because in the cold of winter, there's less sweat, so it may not conduct as well, but I don't remember having issues ever in years past.

Comment: I've seen odd readings from my $20 chinese cheap HRM, and sometimes its due to positioning.  If the strap is a bit slack and the unit slides down to rest on top of my tummy, the readings are off.  It helps to lift the whole thing so its above the nipple line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the battery changes, if you haven't washed the strap, try doing that, first with soap and water, then wipe with isopropyl alcohol. If you get no different response, replace the strap. BTW, I recently had to replace my Edge 305 because the PC drivers were blue screening my Win 7 PC. If you use the Garmin software at all, you might consider an overall upgrade. In addition, they've changed the design f the Garmin HR strap, so if you do decide to replace it, it will be with the newer soft strap, not the same as your original one.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the case here, as it states that problems have been for months, but last summer I had a similar problem, except that the belt was working perfectly. The problem was caused by overtraining and my body was not able to give more than 165 bpm at maximum effort.

A few rest days solved the problem. After that I paid more attention to rest and food intake directly after the ride.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the case for me for sure. My heart rate was saying 100 bpm average for hard workouts.

Answer (score 1):

especially during the winter/cold months static can be an issue (so I read when I was having the exact same problem)...so i sprayed my HR band with Static Cling and it was the first true reading I've seen since I got it over a month ago! Try it and see if it works...

Comment: Sometimes the clothes you're wearing also cause a similar effect.